# Extracting text from html using XPATH

Tags: html, xpath

Here's a bit of an awkward one (I think). I have the following html and am trying to extract the words London and Paris using XPATH.

```
<h2 class="results-title">
    <span class="light">Flights from </span> London
    <span class="light">to</span> Paris    
</h2>
```

The nearest I can get is with the following:

```
//h2[@class='results-title']//span
```

This gives the following results:

Flights from
to

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this will always work in a larger context, but it works for the given toy problem:

```
//h2/text()
```

returns `London` and `Paris`.

Comment: Thanks; sometimes the simplest things are the best! This works perfectly on the html in my XPath tester and fails miserably on my live code. I will ponder over the problem further. I must be missing something else.